# jersey-spring jar is compilation issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, jersey, integration

I want to create a maven jersey spring integrated project. When I am trying to add

> com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.9.1

jar my project is not compiling, without this jar, its working fine.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.jwt.rest</groupId>
      <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>RESTfullApp Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Stacktrace

```
[WARNING] POM for 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:pom:1.9.1:compile' is invalid.

Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[ERROR] An error occurred during dependency resolution of the following artifact:
    org.springframework:spring-core:null
Caused by: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read local copy of metadata: Cannot read metadata from '/home/innoeye/repo2/org/springframework/spring-core/maven-metadata-glassfish-repository.xml': end tag name </body> must match start tag name <hr> from line 5 (position: TEXT seen ...</center>\r\n</body>... @6:8) 
  org.springframework:spring-core:jar:null

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  m2.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2),
  jvnet-nexus-snapshots (https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots),
  glassfish-repository (http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish),
  repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/)

Path to dependency: 
    1) com.jwt.rest:myapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.9.1
```

Comment: Can you try cleaning your repository and try again?

Comment: @ssc I did that, I found probem is in jar itself in its repository.xml file as below <html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.1</center>
</body>
</html> the fifth line having error but, having no solution

Comment: Probably try changing the version

Comment: Finally done, removed it from pom.xml added version 1.8 in classpath through eclipse, now its doing good. thanks @ssc :) :)

Comment: No problem, finally that worked and I learnt something ;)